# View the diff between two branches but ignore some history for each?

Tags: git

##### Problem Description

I start with the following:

```
-A-B-...-E Working Branch 
  \
   H-...-I-J-K-L Feature Branch
```

I want to take J, K, and L, rebase them on top of my working branch (copy of of a development branch), and then make some more changes on top of the working branch to make everything work. Then I want to be able to view all the changes I made to "make everything work" (and only those changes).

#### Problem In Detail

First, I rebase and squash:

```
-A-B-...-E-F Working Branch 
  \
   H-...-I-J-K-L Feature Branch
```

Where F is J-K-L squashed together (with some merge conflict resolution). So far so good. Now I need to make extra changes (G-N-O) on top of E to make everything work due to changes in A to E.

```
-A-B-...-E-F-G-N-O Working Branch 
  \
   H-...-I-J-K-L Feature Branch
```

Okay, and I'm going to slice up F, G, N, & O and organize them a little better into a new series of commits lets call X-Y-Z

```
-A-B-...-E-X-Y-Z Working Branch 
  \
   H-...-I-J-K-L Feature Branch
```

Now I want to see all of the changes I had to make in G, N, and O to update the feature branch to my feature branch, along with all of the merge conflict resolution I had to do when applying F. I thought that `git range-diff I..L E..Z` might be the right thing to do, but because I reorganized F-G into X-Y-Z, `git range-diff` gives me bad diffs I think because it tries to align F with X, so to say, but I'm really only interested in diffing the end states (at L & at Z), without all the changes from A to E. If I set the `--creation-factor` extremely low, it gives me a perfect description of which commits were removed and which ones were added, but that doesn't help me, I want to know how the contents of files were changed.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is simply `git diff F O`. Any reason that wouldn't work? Note the commit IDs still exist in the repo you make them on, even though they are no longer reachable from your branch.

Comment: @TTT Thanks, what about the merge conflict resolutions I had to do when applying F?

Comment: I was thinking that wasn't relevant based on "Now I want to see all of the changes I had to make in G, N, and O", and the conflict resolution was part of `F` before the new commits. Are you saying what you really want is G, N, O and also any changes in F that are only there due to conflict resolution? If you can assume you performed the conflict resolution correctly, I would consider that part of moving J,K,L and not part of the new changes in G,N,O. So maybe it doesn't matter that you had to resolve conflicts in F.

Comment: I'm just thinking how the file contents are different, and conflict resolution could result in differences. What I really want is a diff of Z & L, but without all the extra changes in A-E cluttering up my diff.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your description right :

`X-Y-Z` can be rebased (possibly squashed) on top of `I`.

Once done, check that `git diff L Z'` contains only changes you want to keep.

If this point is confirmed, you can either :

- group the changes as one commit on top of `L`:

```
git reset --soft L
git commit
```

- or move your `Feature` branch to `Z'`

```
git branch -f Feature Z'
```

Comment: Suppose the conflicts resolved in `F` occurred due to changes in commit `B`. Just a hunch-when trying to rebase those resolutions onto `I` (which doesn't have `B`), I think those conflicts resolutions may result in new conflicts again.

Comment: I agree with @TTT's comment; I don't find this to be a satisfactory answer to my question. Rebasing back onto `I` could require merge conflicts which would mean it wouldn't be an exact diff between my working & feature branches any more.

Comment: @karobar on the bright side, it's currently the best answer, by far. ;)

Comment: @karobar: at some point you will have to deal with those conflicts. Did you try to follow these steps? you can always `git rebase --abort` if you are stuck with a complicated conflict during your rebase.

Comment: @LeGEC dealing with the conflicts is not really a problem, I'm just interested in viewing the diff afterward

Comment: @karobar: I'm missing something : `git diff E Z` ?

Comment: @LeGEC That will include all of the changes in `F`, which is a very large change and I'm not interested in. This clutters up my diff considerably.

Comment: this actually isn't for my benefit but for another developer on my team who requested this diff, but I've seen this pop before in the past. If I've dusted off an old feature branch, it seems like it should be easy to see what I had to do when applying the feature branch onto a development branch, without considering all of the changes of the feature branch itself.

Comment: The alternative we are doing right now is to make a new copy the feature branch, then merge the development branch into that copy, then squash `X-Y-Z` and then apply that squashed version. This works but it would be nice if we could avoid making this new branch, and the merging in of the development branch is huge and messy.